# Como compilar uma KB Gx X Ev 2 "na mão"? Via código

Tags: genexus

Como compilar uma KB Gx X Ev 2 "na mão"? Via código.

Eu tenho um programa gerado pelo genexus, que quando abro via ferramenta mostra uma versao desatualizada do mesmo, mas o .cs esta ok. Preciso gerar a DLL desse programa, por isso da pergunta. Compilar um programa do genexus na via prompt de comando.

Answer (score -1):

Valdo,

Há algum tempo atrás escrevi em meu blog (https://beyondgenexus.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/recompilando-toda-a-aplicacao-sem-fazer-build-all/) um artigo falando exatamente sobre isso.

Na época acho que era em gx 9, mas deve te atender.

Qualquer dúvida, é só perguntar!

Comment: Complementando, após realizar o touch no .exe, você deverá executar:

gxexec "**<SuaPastaWeb>**\bld**<seumain>**.cs" -r:GxBaseBuilder.dll -arg:csc="_C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe_"

Notar que o último parâmetro é o caminho para o compilador do c#, caso utilize outra versão, basta alterar...